# Laravel Homestead - Connect to remote DB via SSH Tunnel

Tags: mysql, laravel, ssh, homestead

I want to develop locally using Laravel Homestead, but Laravel should be connected to a remote DB via SSH Tunnel, not the Homestead one.

Somehow I cannot find out how to do so. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a Laravel problem, this an operating system one. You can setup your Tunnel:

```
ssh -L 3307:ec2-172-16-139-19.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3306 deploy@ec2-174-129-17-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Where

3307 is the **local port**,

ec2-172-16-139-19.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com is the **database host**,

3306 is the **listening port**,

deploy is the **database username**, and

ec2-174-129-17-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com is the **remote host**.

Then you just need to configure your Laravel connection to connect to

```
'mysql' => [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 3307,
],
```

Open your `config/database.php` and add find your mysql connection.

Comment: Wow Thx! The ssh command worked perfectly I can connect to the remote db using sequel pro with localhost and 3307. However I cannot find where to put these Laravel settings.

Comment: Open your `config/database.php` and add find your mysql connection.

Comment: That's the problem. There is no database.php or config folder. According to the official documentation I thought I had to put this in the .env file but I didn't find that one either. Perhaps Im too much of a noob :) "A homestead database is configured for both MySQL and Postgres out of the box. For even more convenience, Laravel's .env file configures the framework to use this database out of the box."

Comment: Are you creating a Laravel application? If yes, you have to have a config/database.php file https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php

Comment: Ah, Im trying to run Craft CMS on laravel homestead. Probably thats the reason why there is no config/database.php. Just need to change database settings in craft cms :) What an idiot I am. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes. You have to find the connection config on CraftCMS and set localhost and 3307, and you should be good.

Comment: Had to run your ssh line in the vagrant box itself (vagrabt ssh) to get craft cms inside laravel homestead  connected to the remote db. Everything works like a charm now! Many thx, you saved my evening!

Answer (score -1):

ssh -i ~/openssh_key -L YOUR_PORT:DATABASE_HOST:DB_PORT USERNAME@REMOTE_HOST